# Android json not working in the "IF"

Tags: java, android, json

My code does not work from the `if (jsonObject.names().Get(0).equals("success"))`

```
request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            if(jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("success")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SUCCESS "+jsonObject.getString("success"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),aprenderActivity.class));
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" +jsonObject.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

In the php file

```
{ "success": " Welcome teste"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below solution that will work.

```
if(jsonObject.getString("success").equals(" Welcome teste")){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SUCCESS "+jsonObject.getString("success"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),aprenderActivity.class));
}else {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" +jsonObject.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: not worked yet ... it seems he does not go into OnResponse or in the line If

Comment: can you do debug? see what is printing in the logcat.

Comment: response is not coming properly. please check server side. Response is something string and you trying that to convert it in jsonObject.